# Java Concurrency: HashMap Vs ConcurrentHashMap when concurrent threads only remove elements

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

i have a main thread that creates a HashMap, adds multiple runnable objects to it and then starts each runnable (passing the HashMap to each). The runnable removes its object from the map just before it is about to finish processing.

I would like to know if there is any reason to use a ConcurrentHashMap (rather than a HashMap) in this case - the only operation the runnables perform on the map is to remove themselves from it. Is there a concurrency consideration that necessitates the use of ConcurrentHashMap in this case?

### Main thread

```
private final Map<Integer, Consumer> runnableMap = new HashMap<>();

Runnable runnable;

for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_RUNNABLES; i++) {
    runnable = new Consumer(i, runnableMap);
    runnableMap.put(i, runnable);
    executionContext.execute(runnable);
}
```

### Consumer implements Runnable

```
private final Integer consumerNumber;
private final Map<Integer, Consumer> runnableMap;

public Consumer(int consumerNumber, final Map<Integer, Consumer> runnableMap){
    this.consumerNumber = consumerNumber;
    this.runnableMap = runnableMap;
}

public void run() {
    :::
    // business logic
    :::
    // Below remove is the only operation this thread executes on the map
    runnableMap.remove(consumerNumber);
}
```

Comment: The code to remove an item from a map is not an atomic operation in `HashMap`. And there will be visibility issues as well. You must use thread-safe `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Kartik - Thanks! But since the runnables dont read or update any elements from map i am unclear about the visibility problems that can manifest in this case. Will the main thread be able to see a runnable element on the map that has already finished execution?

Comment: Why? Why not just run a `Queue` of `Runnables`? Why not then feed that queue to an `ExecutorService`? What's the map for?

Comment: `passing a copy of the HashMap to each` this is not a copy since it seems like a reference to the same object.

Comment: michalk - you are right. Its the same HashMap. I have made the correction.

Comment: user207421 - I have explained my reasoning for the map in my response to Martin'sRun post below. If there is a better way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The [javadoc of `HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l88) says:

> **Note that this implementation is not
>   synchronized.**
>
> If multiple threads access a hash map
>   concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map
>   structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.  (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one
>   or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key
>   that an instance already contains is not a structural
>   modification.)  This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on
>   some object that naturally encapsulates the map.

As mentioned above, deletion is a structural change and you must use synchronization.

Furthermore, in the [`removeNode()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l808) method of Hashmap (which is called by the `remove()` method), the `modCount` variable is incremented, which is responsible for `ConcurrentModificationException`. So you might get this exception if you remove elements without synchronization.

Therefore you must use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: re: _you must use a ConcurrentHashMap_ – OP can get correct concurrent behavior using `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Hashtable`. It is not absolute that only `ConcurrentHashMap` will work.

Comment: @kaan First, the OP asked between HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap and not Hashtable. Second, Hashtable is considered obsolete. ConcurrentHashMap performs better than Hashtable as it doesn't require locking.

Comment: Agree, OP asked about those two, but for general awareness there is a third option. Hashtable has been around since JDK 1.0, but it's still available and not deprecated. Saying OP "must use" X is not correct.

Comment: @kaan why don't you mention BlockingQueue and semaphores and locks for _general awareness_? They all can be used in this case. With "must use" I meant "as compared to HashMap". Still not a good reason to downvote.

Comment: Kartik - Thanks very much! I found the Javadoc reference above you provided very helpful. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your reason for doing this is to track thread completion, why not use a CountdownLatch? Not sure if a HashMap can have concurrency issues only on remove, I recommend use it only if your code will not break on any possible issue, or go with a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Thanks Martin! The runnables are actually long running listeners that will terminate only in case of exceptions. At any given moment, i want to able to determine the number of active runnables from the map and gather some statistics from each runnable object. The main thread periodically polls the map to compensate for any "dead" runnables (by adding a new one).

Answer (score -2):

You asked about differences between `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`, but there is an additional data structure to consider: `Hashtable`. There are differences and trade-offs for each. You will need to evaluate which is the best fit for your intended usage.

- `HashMap` is unsynchronized, so if more than one thread can read from or write to it, your results will be unpredictable. `HashMap` also permits null as key or value.
- `Hashtable` is synchronized, doesn't support null keys or values. From [the Hashtable Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

  > *Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.*
- `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe, doesn't allow null to be used as a key or value.

Comment: Thanks Kaan! Given the fact that the runnables only remove their own instance from the map and dont read/update any element, are there any threadsafety concerns to worry about in this case? Could you help me understand whether my main thread would instantly see the remove than happens within each runnable with a HashMap implementation?

Comment: It might be possible to use a non-concurrent structure in your case, but I would caution you to think it through thoroughly. If you end up reasoning that you don't need concurrency protections but you're wrong, you might encounter very confusing behavior. There are reasons to avoid unnecessary concurrency protections for speed/performance considerations, but in general I would start with code that is provably correct, and only later consider optimizing your data structures (_maybe_).

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is not synchronized, but it is thread-safe.